# Exclude All and keep one Django Query

Tags: django

This is my Query where i am getting all users who are manager and employee.

```
User.objects.exclude(
            Q(userprofile__user_is_deleted = True)|
            Q(userprofile__user_company__company_is_deleted=True)
            ).filter(
                Q(userprofile__user_company =company_name) 
            )
```

Now i want to query such that when logged in user is manager, then exclude all manager except him (the logged in user which is manager)

```
if request.user.userprofile.user_role.id == 3: # 3 for manager
            context['users'] = context['users'].exclude()
```

I am not getting how to query. How can i do it.

Comment: It is used for Complex Query - `from django.db.models import Q`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
users = context['users']
one_manager_all_employee = users.exclude(userprofile__user_role_id=3) | User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk)
```

Or you can use [union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#union) as well:

```
users = context['users']
all_employee_qset = users.exclude(userprofile__user_role_id=3)
all_employee_one_manager = all_employee_qset.union(User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk)
```